# Upload Image to Opencart

Tags: delphi, opencart

I am trying to upload an image to Opencart via `TRestRequest`. My code looks like this:

```
mRestClient.BaseURL := ...; // opencart url
mRequest.Resource := 'index.php?route=rest/product_admin/productimages&id=...';
mRequest.AddParameter('x-oc-restadmin-id', token);
mRequest.Params[0].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;

jpg := TMemoryStream.Create;
jpg.LoadFromFile('image.jpg');
mRequest.AddBody(jpg, TRESTContentType.ctIMAGE_JPEG);

mRequest.Execute;
```

I got a success response from the API, but no image is uploaded. My Opencart version is 3.0.2.

Comment: Try adding `jpg.Position := 0;` after loading the file.

Comment: i also add jpg.Position := 0; but still same problem.